# open a pop up a window in a webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

I'm currently creating an image map with `webview`. When someone clicks on the hotspots, I'd like to open up another html page named `getdir.html` in a popup window of some kind on the same page. I'm guessing I'd need to use JavaScript, but I'm totally new to JavaScript. How can I do this?

This is my code for webview :

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/imagemap.html");
```

this is my image map :

```
      <html>
        <body>

        <img src="bed_sa.png"
         border="0"

        usemap ="#imgmap2" />

<script>
function openPopup(url) {
    window.open(url, "popup_id", "width=100,height=200");
    return false;
}
</script>

        <map id="imgmap2" name="imgmap2">
<area shape="rect" alt="first place" title="" coords="139,310,167,342" href="getdir.html" onclick="return openPopup(this.href);" target="" />
<area shape="rect" alt="sec place" title="" coords="142,543,171,571" href="getdir.html" onclick="return openPopup(this.href);" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="thirrd palce" title="" coords="331,630,358,658" href="getdir.html" onclick="return openPopup(this.href);" target="_self" />
       </map>
         </body>
        </html>
```

**Edit**:
I've tried to open the pop up in JavaScript which is working fine on my computer when I click on the html separately, but not when using webview on device.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I never try this, but something You have to use Javascript for this, which will open a new window with your getdir.html file. call java script function on map area click. Also 
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
for your webview.

Comment: Actually, I did something like before few months but in my case it was html5 and javascript and it works perfectly in android device. Also I fetched co-ordinates from webpage database.

Comment: hey thanks for rpl i tried that but not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript:

```
alert("your text here")
```

Comment: hey thanks but i want to open another html page inside the alert.